# NullPointerException when getting elements from Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the names of the employees and their department and location from a list of the names and id numbers and I keep getting the `NullPointerException` even though it prints all of the names and locations. It then stops the build and doesn't xecute the print department and print location methods.

I've tried re-doing the `for` loops and seeing if any one data point was the problem but it seems to happen if I do the loop for all of the `Employee` objects or if I just do one.

```
package homework5_parth_desai;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Party Parth
 */
public class Homework5_Parth_Desai {

    public static int emplIndex = -1;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("acmeEgr.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        Employee[] emp = new Employee[50];
        String s = "";
        String t = "";
        int r = 0;

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {    //scans in file 
            emplIndex++;
            emp[emplIndex] = new Employee();
            if (scan.hasNextLine() == true) {    //takes first line as first name, second as last naem and third as id number and tehn ccreates an object out of that
                s = scan.nextLine();                   
            }
            if (scan.hasNextLine() == true) {
                t = scan.nextLine();
            }
            if (scan.hasNextLine() == true) {
                r = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            }

            emp[emplIndex].Employee(s, t, r);

            // TODO code application logic here
        }

        printAll(emp);

        printDepartment("IT", emp);

        printLocation("Auburn Hills", emp);

    }

    static void printAll(Employee[] ppl) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ppl.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ppl[i].toString());
        }
    }

    static void printDepartment(String title, Employee[] ppl) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ppl.length; i++) {
            if (title.equals(ppl[i].getDept())) {
                System.out.println(ppl[i].getName() + " is in " + ppl[i].getLocation());
            }
        }
    }

    static void printLocation(String loc, Employee[] ppl) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ppl.length; i++) {
            if (loc.equals(ppl[i].getLocation())) {
                System.out.println(ppl[i].getName() + "  is in " + ppl[i].getDept());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Small exert of the `.txt` file:

```
Alexander
Seiber
10010
Zehua
Showalter
20010
Cassidy
Woodle
20030
Randall
Shaukat
10030
Pam
Korda
10020
Justin
Polito
20030
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int emplIndex = -1;
```

Why is the index maintained as a `static` field? Don't do that.

```
Employee[] emp = new Employee[50];
```

The employee array has a fixed size of `50` elements, however

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
```

this loop is based on the lines of the `acmeEgr.txt` file, which might be **more** than `50`.
In that case, you'll get an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` first

```
emp[emplIndex] = new Employee();
```

or a `NullPointerException` after

```
emp[emplIndex].Employee(s, t, r);
```

---

Instead, if the lines are **less** then `50`, this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ppl.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(ppl[i].toString());
}
```

will still loop all the `50` elements, because

```
ppl.length = 50
```

Thus, this line

```
ppl[i].toString()
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`.
This is what happens if the elements are, for example, `40`

```
System.out.println(ppl[0].toString());
System.out.println(ppl[1].toString());
System.out.println(ppl[2].toString());
System.out.println(ppl[3].toString());
...
System.out.println(ppl[40].toString()); // ppl[40] is null, NullPointerException!
```

Comment: thank you very much, the file only had 41 people so i used the static int empIndex as the end of my for loops instead of ppl.length and now she works to prfection.  Sad it took me 3 hours and the interent to figure that one out

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a much easier array type to deal with. Try using it instead of a normal array, because then you don't have to deal with indexes.

Comment: i would love to but we have to use array for the assignment